# Ubuntu 16.04 Live USB Gnome Terminal not opening by any means

Tags: live-usb, gnome-terminal, 16.04

Just downloaded Ubuntu 16.04 - i686 and created a live USB with LiLi USB installer. While Trying Ubuntu, can't open Gnome Terminal, neither by clicking the icon, nor by `ctrl+alt+t`. Can anyone assist please?

Regards

Comment: Try again with [Rufus](http://rufus.akeo.ie) and see what happens.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem after upgrading from Ubuntu 15.10. I needed to reconfigure my locales.

Before you do this: Remember that you get back to the GUI ("normal screen") by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd>

**Open Text-and-Terminal Emulator (without GUI)**

Press:  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>

**Reconfigure Locales**

```
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
$ sudo locale-gen "en_US.UTF-8"
$ sudo localectl set-locale LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
```

**Confirm result**

```
$ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US:en
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=en_US.UTF-8
LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8
LC_NAME=en_US.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=en_US.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=en_US.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

and

```
$ locale -a
C
C.UTF-8
en_US.utf8
POSIX
```

**Switch back to GUI**

Press:  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd>

Terminal should now work again. You might have to reboot.

Comment: The first command worked for me. Brought up a graphical interface where I selected the locale and my terminal was up and running.

Answer (score 1):

Many programs that exist for creating a bootable Linux installer on a USB stick don't work very well with Ubuntu. UUI is one of the wordt, and LiLi isn't much better.

Using [Rufus](http://rufus.akeo.ie) has fixed a lot of issues for those trying to install Ubuntu from a flash drive. Use that instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try Ctrl+Alt+F1, this opens a "tty terminal" or terminal with no GUI. Use Ctrl+Alt+F7 to return to the GUI.

Comment: We can certainly access command line in different methods, but why not the default option working that wonders me.

Comment: No offense, but there is no different. I guess you could just live with it and be done...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I try to install Ubuntu 16.04 on my lenovo laptop. I couldn't open terminal from my live usb installer. I couldn't even be able to open installer to install in my laptop. It happened because Ubuntu image is not downloaded properly even though it shows download successfully. So I posted same problem on Ubuntu forums. You can check the thread [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2324615)

I downloaded fresh Ubuntu image from the official site. I then checked md5sum. After I made sure it is downloaded correctly, I made a live USB installer. And then I installed successfully in my laptop.
To check md5sum execute following commad.

```
me@linux:$ md5sum ubuntu-16.04-desktop-amd64.iso
c94d54942a2954cf852884d656224186
```

The result should match the md5sum hash value [in this page](http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04/MD5SUMS) for respective OS. Please refer to the thread(first) link I've provided for further information.

Comment: Did you check that link? My whole answer is a brief description of that link. And I also posted the solution that worked for me. Thank you..