# gnome terminal is not working in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

I followed this answer :https://askubuntu.com/a/788896/682092 but when I execute command `locale`.I get the following result:

```
$ locale
LANG=C
LANGUAGE=C
LC_CTYPE="C"
LC_NUMERIC=C
LC_TIME=C
LC_COLLATE="C"
LC_MONETARY=C
LC_MESSAGES="C"
LC_PAPER=C
LC_NAME=C
LC_ADDRESS=C
LC_TELEPHONE=C
LC_MEASUREMENT=C
LC_IDENTIFICATION=C
LC_ALL=
```

I am working on **Nvidia Jetson TK1**
My terminal still doesn't work: **When I double click on the terminal it doesn't open without giving any error**.

Xterm works on my machine though.

How do I fix the issue?

Comment: You need to be more specific than "Doens't work". What happens when you try to lanuch it? Any error messages? What other terminal does work (xterm?)? What changed? Did it ever work?

Comment: @popey i have edited the question

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you want to achieve and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them in their entirety in your question ([edit]). You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. (see [How do I ask a good question?](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask))

Answer (score 0):

Just copy this to your `locale` file located in `/etc/default/`

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US:en
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=en_US.UTF-8
LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8
LC_NAME=en_US.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=en_US.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=en_US.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

Now restart your machine.